# Namespace/class/method not showing in log file when parameters more than 2

Tags: c#, wcf, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have a WCF service application, and in its Web.config, I defined the following log4net configuration:

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="F:\InternalAPIServer\logs\InternalAPIServer.log"/>
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
    <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] [%-5p] %C.%M - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

In the codes, when I called the logger with one or two parameters:

```
Log.InfoFormat("Server certificate validity dates: [{0} - {1}].", ServerCertificate.GetEffectiveDateString(), ServerCertificate.GetExpirationDateString());
```

The log show up ok in the log file:

```
2017-02-14 17:12:01,056 [12] [INFO ] InternalAPIServer.Connection.ValidateServerCertficate - Server certificate validity dates: [31/5/2016 8:00:00 AM - 7/6/2017 8:00:00 PM].
```

But when I called the logger with three parameters:

```
Log.InfoFormat("Server certificate issuer: [{0}], validity dates: [{1} - {2}].", ServerCertificate.Issuer, ServerCertificate.GetEffectiveDateString(), ServerCertificate.GetExpirationDateString());
```

The log is no longer ok because the namespace, class and method name became "?.?":

```
2017-02-14 17:22:01,056 [12] [INFO ] ?.? - Server certificate issuer: [CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA, O=DigiCert Inc], C=US, validity dates: [31/5/2016 8:00:00 AM - 7/6/2017 8:00:00 PM].
```

Why is that so? How do I keep the namespace, class and method name from been suppressed when the number of parameters to the logger is more than two?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly aware of the parameters you're supposed to use with Log4Net, but your error must be happening from because you should be passing a plain string.

You can do that by using `String.Format()`.

```
string message = String.Format("Server certificate issuer: [{0}], validity dates: [{1} - {2}].",
    ServerCertificate.Issuer, 
    ServerCertificate.GetEffectiveDateString(), 
    ServerCertificate.GetExpirationDateString())

Log.InfoFormat(message);
```

So therefore, you should be able to alternatively use

```
Log.InfoFormat(String.Format("{0} {1}", string1, string2));
```